# CSS to select Even rows along with another condition

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table with a few rows having a class - .childtables I want to select (using CSS) all even rows which do not have the .childtables class.

I tried the following

```
tr:not(.childtables):nth-child(even) {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

I can try jQuery as follows

```
$("table tr:not(.childtables)").filter(":even")
```

Is there any way to avoid jQuery and achieve this using plain CSS?

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no CSS selector that allows you to select even-numbered matches of a selector. You'll have to use your jQuery solution.

Note that `:nth-child()` is 1-indexed and jQuery index selectors are 0-indexed, so `:nth-child(even)` should correspond to `:odd` instead. Of course, that's just a general statement; what you are trying to match depends on your own structure.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: The 2nd `tr:not(.childtables)` is not being selected because it is the 3rd child of the table. Try jQuery `:odd` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Oh, than it goes for a vote, but surprisingly, jQuery starts from first `tr` where CSS doesn't... may be cuz it starts from 0

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Yes, that's where the 1-index and 0-index stuff comes in.